# How to get a metric name from Actuator Prometheus endpoint

Tags: java, spring

My Spring Boot application reads data from Kafka, validates and sends to another Kafka. There might be some mistakes in incoming messages while validation, and these messages come to DltHandler. Metrics are gathered by Prometheus and sent to Grafana. Each time when an invalid message comes, the counter of Dlt topic messages in Actuator Prometheus increases.

The fact is that when Dlt topic is read and all messages removed, the metric of Dlt topic messages stores the last value of messages q-ty.

What is needed - to reset this counter to zero after all messages are read and removed.

I have tried MeterRegistry.get but have no idea how to find correct metric name in Actuator Prometheus endpoint.

For example:

```
# HELP kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_consumed_total The total number of records consumed
# TYPE kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_consumed_total counter kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_consumed_total{client_id="consumer-data2-9",kafka_version="3.1.2",spring_id="not.managed.by.Spring.consumer-data2-9",}
21.0
```

What is metric name to be put in MeterRegistry.get(metric name) and how to proceed to reset this metric into zero?